# How to join two hashMap by their key

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have two HashMap. I need to join the two hashMap by their key.

```
Map<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
firstMap= [{K1,V1},{K2,V2}]
secondMap= [{K2,V2},{K3,V3}]
```

I need my third map to have

```
thirdMap= [{K2,V2}]
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do what you need:

```
Map<String, String> thirdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (String key : firstMap.keySet()) {
    if (secondMap.containsKey(key)) {
        thirdMap.put(key, firstMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
firstMap.keySet().retainAll(secondMap.keySet());
```

This assumes you are allowed to change firstMap. If not, make a copy first:

```
Map<String, String> thirdMap = new HashMap<>(firstMap);
```

Then

```
thirdMap.keySet().retainAll(secondMap.keySet());
```

Comment: This ends up with `K1` and `K3` in the final map, which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: Indeed, not sure what I was thinking. I thought he wanted to join them like the title says. :)

Answer (score 2):

Google Guava library have a utility [`MapDifference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference(java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map)) which gives the difference between two map.

```
MapDifference<String, String> diff = Maps.difference(map1, map2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
Map<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> join = new HashMap<>();

for (Entry<String, String> entry : firstMap.entrySet())
    if (secondMap.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
        String value = secondMap.get(entry.getKey());
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            join.put(entry.getKey(), value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this answer also makes sure that the values are equal and not only the keys. Is that what you intended?

Comment: no. I just need the keys to be same. Value can be different.

Answer (score 2):

Map firstMap = new HashMap();
    Map secondMap = new HashMap();

```
 // Add everything in firstMap 
    map2.putAll(Maps.difference(firstMap , secondMap ).entriesOnlyOnLeft());
```